# В xUbuntu 11.10 Voyager нет звука

Tags: аудио, xubuntu

Здравствуйте.

ОС: Windows 7 & xUbuntu 11.10 Voyager

Звуковая карта: Asus Xonar DS Audio

В xUbuntu не работает звук. В параметрах звука отображается звуковая карта Xonar DS (Alsa mixer) каналы выбраны все, что можно, везде звук включен, но его нету. В Windows все работает отлично. Есть идеи с чем может быть проблема?

```
head -n 1 /proc/asound/card*/codec#*
```

> `==> /proc/asound/card0/codec#0 <==Codec: Realtek ALC888`
>
> `==> /proc/asound/card0/codec#3 <==Codec: Nvidia MCP77/78 HDMI`

```
uname -a
```

> `Linux four 3.0.0-14-generic #23-Ubuntu SMP Mon Nov 21 20:28:43 UTC 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

```
cat /proc/asound/version
```

> `Advanced Linux Sound Architecture Driver Version 1.0.24.`

```
aplay -l
```

> `Список PLAYBACK устройств`
>
> `карта 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], устройство 0: ALC888 Analog [ALC888 Analog]  Подустройства: 0/1  Подустройство №0: subdevice #0карта 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], устройство 1: ALC888 Digital [ALC888 Digital]  Подустройства: 1/1  Подустройство №0: subdevice #0карта 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], устройство 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]  Подустройства: 1/1  Подустройство №0: subdevice #0карта 1: DS [Xonar DS], устройство 0: Multichannel [Multichannel]  Подустройства: 1/1  Подустройство №0: subdevice #0карта 1: DS [Xonar DS], устройство 1: Digital [Digital]  Подустройства: 1/1  Подустройство №0: subdevice #0`

Заранее благодарю за помощь.

Comment: Пытался выполнить советы указанные здесь - http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1681577о в итоге на 6-м пункте выдало ошибку "ioctl32_new.c:23:28: фатальная ошибка: linux/smp_lock.h: Нет такого файла или каталогакомпиляция прервана." и в итоге установка прекратилась и дальнейшие действия не хотят выполняться ссылая на то, что требуется сперва выполнить предыдущие скрипты. Есть идеи как исправить эту ситуацию?

Comment: Решено! Удалил pulseaudio оставил alsamixer и отключил встроенную звуковую карту. Не знаю, конечно, что послужило решением, может все вместе, может лишь отключение звуковой, разбираться нет желания!